# adding adwords tracking to a Click instead of a page load using goog_report_conversion

Tags: users, google-analytics

I am using the simple subscription module to subscribe users to a newsletter and wish to track clicks of subscribers.  Is there an easy way to call the goog_report_conversion() function when someone clicks on the subscribe button? I don't see any configuration for this with the simple subscription module.

Comment: Simple subscription is meant to be simple, and the only way to do it is to remove features that are not universally needed. You can always check who subscribed, and that's what most people care about.

Comment: Hi Molot, Yes I know who subscribed but I use adwords and it would be great to know what ad was clicked on - hence the need to add tracking directly on the subscribe button.  Anyway to do that, or do I need to redirect subscribers to a separate thank you page and place tracking there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General advice: don't use "simple" modules for non-simple tasks.

No easy way here, you need to inject your JavaScript code, and [attach additional behavior](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors) to that button. Worse, you would need to make sure there is **enough time** for function to process. My colleagues use *thank you page* if feasible for that very reason - browser will do it's best to minimize time between button click and page load. On *thank you page* that is not an issue.